# How to share session variables in two different web applications?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have two different web applications: Phase I and Phase II.

Phase II has a dependancy on phase I for some session values.

I want to run these two applications with sharing session variables.

I don't want to use state server to store session.

I have used inproc session and I want to share this session together.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

you cant share the session between 2 apps with in-proc sessions because in-proc session runs within the context of an application. you can share the session only by taking it out of the application's context which is possible only with out-proc session mode.

Comment: there is one way that you build your state manager and expose it as a service to both your apps. however, in my opinion this would be quite a bit of an effort to circumvent the usage of out-proc sessions.

Comment: and i dont really think that it would be worth avoding to use out-proc session mode and building your own from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this [LINK](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-(aspnet_state).aspx) i guess it might help you setting things up.